# XMLNS : a way to set them once for all?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xml-namespaces

We have multiple namespaces and assemblies in my project, and so many xmlns to declare in each control we make (at least 7, without system ones like x: or d:). It's so tedious.

Is there a way to declare xmlns once for all in the application ?
If not, do you have some workarounds (in order to have a lightweight control definition) ?

Please note that I know XmlnsDefinitionAttribute, it's not always possible (with external ssemblies for example) or not a great design (for me it's not a great design to put an UI specific attribute in a business entity assembly).

Answer (score 4):

`xmlns` are a document level thing needed by the compiler, they are like `using` statements which you will also have to place in every C# code file.

If you have many common `xmlns` you could create an [item template for Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx) which adds them by default, or find an extension which allows for something like Snippets in `XAML`.

Comment: Xmlns are like using, Ok. Except that for "using" I can encapsulate them in a region and use ALT+SHIFT+F10+ENTER to easily add a missing one when I use a non referenced class. No wasted space, no wasted time, all natively supported. Not the same in Xaml. :/
Your proposal of item template is interesting (XAML Snippet even more) but I have no good memories on item templates. I'll have a look at Xaml Snippet. Thanks for answer.

Comment: PS : 01000110 00110001 00100000 01101110 01101111 01110100 00100000 01100001 01110110 01100001 01101001 01101100 01100001 01100010 01101100 01100101 00100000 01101111 01101110 00100000 01111000 01101101 01101100 01101110 01110011 00100000 00111010 00101001

Comment: I think the F1 support in XAML is pretty good. When i wrote my answer it also came to my mind that Smart-tags (i use `Ctrl+.`) in XAML would be great though, e.g. you write a class: `local:MyClass`, get a Smart-tag and it inserts the `xmlns:local="..."` for you.